# X86 platform access to peripheral registers is very slow

Tags: x86, dpdk

I use AMD's cryptodev through DPDK, but I found that the most time-consuming thing is actually register access in the DPDK cryptodev driver.

```
    struct timespec time_start = { 0, 0 }, time_end = { 0, 0 };
    clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &time_start);
    printf("start time %lus,%lu ns\n", time_start.tv_sec, time_start.tv_nsec);
    cur_head_offset = CCP_READ_REG(b_info->cmd_q->reg_base, CMD_Q_HEAD_LO_BASE);
    clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &time_end);
    printf("end   time %lus,%lu ns\n", time_end.tv_sec, time_end.tv_nsec);
    printf("duration:%lds %ldns\n", time_end.tv_sec-time_start.tv_sec, time_end.tv_nsec-time_start.tv_nsec);
```

It output

```
start time 1616032196s,470511856 ns
end   time 1616032196s,470516756 ns
duration:0s 4900ns
start time 1616032196s,470523966 ns
end   time 1616032196s,470527946 ns
duration:0s 3980ns
```

Just like the time output above, a register access takes 4us. Are there other ways to quickly access peripheral registers?

---

After the reminder in the comment area, I corrected my test code:

```
    uint64_t start, end;
    start = rte_get_hpet_cycles();
    for (i = 0;i < 1000000; ++i){
        cur_head_offset = CCP_READ_REG(b_info->cmd_q->reg_base,
                        CMD_Q_HEAD_LO_BASE);
    }
    end = rte_get_hpet_cycles();
    printf("start : %lu %lu\n", start, rte_get_hpet_hz());
    printf("end : %lu %lu\n", end, rte_get_hpet_hz());
    double time = (double)(end - start)/(double)rte_get_hpet_hz();
    printf("Average per operation %lf ns\n", time / 1000000 * 1000 * 1000 * 1000);
```

Output:

```
start : 2301456683 14318180
end : 2309549122 14318180
Average per operation 565.186288 ns
```

It's good.

Comment: can you help me understand the question a bit more, DPDK implements crypto PMD library for accessing Software based Crypto like `openssl, aesni-mb` and hardware like `qat, NXP, marvell` crypto engine. CCP_READ_REG is used in AMD’s cryptographic co-processor register read. So is your question `AMD crypto processor access is taking more time, what should be done to speed up?`. can you please share details of processor, os, dpdk version too.

Comment: `printf("start time %lus,%lu ns\n",` is *inside* your timed region.  So you're timing a write() system call as well as the `CCP_READ_REG` work you want to do.

Comment: Have you tried putting a bunch of these ops into a loop, to see what kind of throughput you get for multiple accesses?  (That would also factor out timing measurement overhead - `clock_gettime` avoids a round trip into the kernel thanks to the VDSO, but still takes many nanoseconds.)  That would also let OoO exec do its magic if you have any independent work to overlap with MMIO access, or if they're pipelined at all.

Comment: @ Vipin Varghese Thank you for your reply, my computer information is: AMD® Ryzen 7 1700x eight-core processor × 16, DPDK.20.11, OS is Centos 7. I modified my test code and it seems to perform well. As you said, I hope to speed up the access to AMD crypto processor, and would be happy to listen to your suggestions.

Comment: @ Peter Cordes: That is a shameful error. I have modified it in the description of the problem, and I specified the GCC compilation option as -O0 to avoid the compiler from optimizing the code flow. If there are still errors, please correct me.

Comment: @VipinVarghese I also visited your homepage and found that you are an expert in DPDK, so I want to ask again about the `rte_mem_virt2phy()` api, which is used in DPDK to get the physical address from the virtual address. But it seems that it needs to access the file system to get the address mapping, which is fatal to performance-sensitive programs. So I hope to find a way to replace `rte_mem_virt2phy()`. By the way, I set IOVA mode is RTE_IOVA_PA, because the AMD crypto processor cannot correctly identify the virtual address without IOMMU.

Comment: @VipinVarghese In addition, I have another discovery: The difference between the physical address and the virtual address obtained by `rte_mem_virt2phy()` is fixed at 0x2440000000. Can I directly add 0x2440000000 in the `RTE_IOVA_PA` mode to get the real physical address?

Comment: @xisme thanks for the kind words, I am not expert in DPDK just sharing what I know. Glad to see your edit has reduced latency for the current question. API `rte_mem_virt2phy` definition shows there is file access done to resolve the address. This is why mempool pktmbuf struct has virt and phy address as part of each element to mitigate the overhead. So answer to second question, needs a bit more context, because DPDK elements are created from huge page, this can be changed with the option `--base-address`. So `0x2440000000` might not prevail next run or different system.